# data migration tool and schema migration tool

Tags: database, database-design, data-migration, database-migration

Currently we are using Yii framework for web development. However some developer recommended using python. Now we have aournd 90 tables, and are going to support several database systems, such as mysql, sqlite, postgresql, etc  for our clients. We would like the sql file(s) (schemas, index, views or whatever) to be independent with DB system. So please recommend a nice schema migration tool, and also what is best-fit data migration tool in this situation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many answers to my similar question [Can you recommend a database schema migration tool that is not tied to a particular framework or ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3923280/445073) Given that you have not yet settled on your python web framework, perhaps you should also look for a migration tool which is not tied to any particular framework? This leaves you free to change your framework and your migration tool independently.

I never got a chance to try out any of the suggestions given in the answers to my question, but the two candidates that I would investigate first are:

- [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/)
- [yoyo-migrations](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yoyo-migrations/4.1.0)

Comment: Thanks, does sqlalchemy-migrate tied to python framework? I also heard about fryway and liquibase. If we use a framework, will a framework-untied tool be a better choice? Thank you, I am a newbie.

Comment: sqlalchemy-migrate uses sqlalchemy which is a SQL toolkit and ORM for python - it is not tied to a web framework and you can use it for migrations without having to use sqlalchemy in your web project if you like.

Comment: For anyone finding this via Google, sqlalchemy-migrate seems to be on life-support at best these days. The user base has been drifting toward [Alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/), which is actually by the author of SQLAlchemy.